# How to define mapping with multiple endpoints in FeignClient?

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-cloud-feign

I created a `@FeignCleint` in my app, with the following mapping:

```
@FeignClient(name="${mongo.service.id}", url="${mongo.service.url}")
public interface MongoBusinessDayDataInterface {
    String requestMappingPrefix = "/api/businessDayData";

    @GetMapping(path = {requestMappingPrefix + "/{businessDate}",
                        requestMappingPrefix + "/{businessDate}/{terminalId}",
                        requestMappingPrefix + "/{businessDate}/{currency}",
                        requestMappingPrefix + "/{businessDate}/{terminalId}/{currency}"})
    BusinessDayData fetchBusinessDayData(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate businessDate,
                                         @PathVariable(required = false) String terminalId,
                                         @PathVariable(required = false) CurrencyType currency);
}
```

when I try to load the app I get the folloeing exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'com.poalim.dc.atm.reconciliation.rest.feign.service.MongoBusinessDayDataInterface': 
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Method fetchBusinessDayDataList can only contain at most 1 value field. 
Found: [/api/businessDayData/list/{businessDate}, /api/businessDayData/list/{businessDate}/{terminalId}, /api/businessDayData/list/{businessDate}/{currency}, /api/businessDayData/list/{businessDate}/{terminalId}/{currency}]
```

if path attribute can receive an array of strings, why does it say it "can only contain at most 1 value field"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@GetMapping` is the annotation from Spring Web module, which is commonly used in controllers of the server apps.

By default, Feign doesn't support these kind of annotations. It has [its own set of them](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#interface-annotations). For example, `@RequestLine` supports only one path.

`spring-cloud-openfeign` adds additional support  to use spring-web's annotations for feign clients purely for developer's convenience (look at [SpringMvcContract](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/support/SpringMvcContract.java)). But, in this case, there are some annotations' signature mismatches which you should ignore in this case.

By the way, it's logically pointless to set multiple paths when you use Feign. It's a client, so it should know which path would be selected when you make a request through it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. why is it pointless though? when the request is made, it will know which path to select, by the path variables that will/will not be null. no?

Comment: Aww, this is really interesting case, probably the one and only when this functionality would be helpful. Unfortunately, Feign doesn't support it now, probably due to the rarity of this case. See [the similar discussion](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1826). But, again, this should be made in plain Feign (with `@RequestLine` annotation) first, then it could be supported in `spring-cloud-openfeign`.